# jQuery selector NOT as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a method that generate the string selector to use to bind an `input` event on an element.

I'm facing to a little problem, for now my code works but not perfectly.
If `not_validated = true` then it doesn't matter the value of `valid/invalid` because my select will select them anyway. I'm looking for a way to exclude the elements that have some classes. See the `TODO` in the source code. Probably something with `^ or !` but I only know the ways that use methods such as `$.hasClass` and so on.

```
FormValidator.prototype.defaultOptions = {
  // Performs live validation, on value change.
  live: {
    not_validated: true,
    valid: true,
    invalid: true
  }
};

// Stuff ...

FormValidator.prototype._generateSelectorOnInput = function() {
  var selector = '';

  if(this.options.live && this.options.live.not_validated){
    selector += '[data-validate]'// TODO: Need to exclude the selector that have INPUT_SUCCESS_CLASS or INPUT_ERROR_CLASS !
  }

  if(this.options.live && this.options.live.valid){
    selector += (selector.length ? ', ' : '') + '[data-validate].' + INPUT_SUCCESS_CLASS
  }

  if(this.options.live && this.options.live.invalid){
    selector += (selector.length ? ', ' : '') + '[data-validate].' + INPUT_ERROR_CLASS
  }

  return selector;
};
```

Comment: The [`':not()'`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector or [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method may be of interest to you.

Comment: See `.not()`. Usage in your case will be `$('[data-validate]').not('.INPUT_SUCCESS_CLASS, .INPUT_ERROR_CLASS')` http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
selector += '[data-validate]:not(.' + INPUT_SUCCESS_CLASS + ', .' + INPUT_ERROR_CLASS + ')';
```